# Javascript, vertical collapse/expand menu - remember after page change

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, menu

I just started building my webshop, so don't mind ALL the other flaws you might encounter, unless they are related to the topic.

I'm currently designing the shop menu, and have a vertical collapse/expand menu build with javascript.

My issue is that, when a link is clicked, and the page switch to the destination, the menu close/resets, which i dont want.

I would like that the menu keeps being expanded after the page has changed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Here is a link to the website my school has provided me with: http://web14.simo9928.iba-abakomp.dk/wordpress/produkt-kategori/fiskegrej/endegrej/fluer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a couple of ways to do this, depending on if you plan to use a web server or not, or have a table in a database set up for user settings, etc.

One of the ways I have found do this is using "Web Storage API"
(see this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API)

It would be better if you gave some sample code so we see what you are working with and maybe give you some "sample solutions." (also, if you post sample code, the answer I gave you, Web Storage API might not be applicable depending on your code, so please share)

Please see below comment for jsfiddle demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I have uploaded some html css and the javascript code to jsfiddle.

The javascript is not getting loaded correctly.

https://jsfiddle.net/j2y278vk/

Just let me know what a solution could be and where to read about it!

Comment: couldn't fully understand your jsfiddle
here's one that I made to demo the web storage api
https://jsfiddle.net/yfuzng1y/1/

Comment: I've been reading about the sessionsstorage and localstorage, and they will be my solution once i figure it out correctly. thanks for your example!